# JSTree: move all child nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I'm using `JSTree`, and this is my setup for the `contextmenu` plugin:

```
"contextmenu":{         
    "items": function($node) {
        return {
            "Remove": {
                "separator_before": false,
                "separator_after": false,
                "label": "Delete group",
                "action": function (obj) {
                    $tree.jstree("get_children_dom", $node).each(function(child){
                        $tree.jstree("move_node", $tree.jstree("get_node", child, true), "#", "last", function(node, parent, pos){
                            alert(1);
                        });
                    });
                    $tree.jstree("delete_node", $node);
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

basically, I want the children of the group that's being deleted to be moved upwards. The function I've currently got should place the nodes at the end, but how can I place them on the deleted node's place? Also, the current code doesn't work - what am I doing wrong?

Last but not least, how can I check the node type before removing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> basically, I want the children of the group that's being deleted to be moved upwards.

If by upwards you mean get into the position of the node that got deleted, check the following example:

```js
var data = [{
  'text': 'item 1',
  'children': [{
    text: 'item 1-1',
    children: [{
      text: 'item 1-1-1',
      children: [{
        text: 'item 1-1-1-1'
      }, {
        text: 'item 1-1-1-2'
      }]
    }, {
      text: 'item 1-1-2'
    }, {
      text: 'item 1-1-3'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'item 1-2',
    children: [{
      text: 'item 1-2-1'
    }, {
      text: 'item 1-2-2'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'item 1-3',
    children: [{
      text: 'item 1-3-1'
    }, {
      text: 'item 1-3-2'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'item 1-4',
    children: [{
      text: 'item 1-4-1'
    }, {
      text: 'item 1-4-2'
    }]
  }]
}, {
  'text': 'item 2',
  children: [{
    text: 'item 2-1',
    children: [{
      text: 'item 2-1-1'
    }, {
      text: 'item 2-1-2'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'item 2-2',
    children: [{
      text: 'item 2-2-1'
    }, {
      text: 'item 2-2-1'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'item 2-3'
  }]
}, {
  'text': 'item 3',
  children: [{
    text: 'item 3-1',
    children: [{
      text: 'item 3-1-1'
    }, {
      text: 'item 3-1-2'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'item 3-2'
  }]
}, {
  'text': 'item 4 (you cannot delete this one)',
  'disableDelete': true,
  children: [{
    text: 'item 4-1'
  }, {
    text: 'item 4-2'
  }, {
    text: 'item 4-3'
  }]
}];

var $tree = $('#jstree_demo').jstree({
  'plugins': ['contextmenu'],
  'core': {
    'animation': 0,
    'check_callback': true,
    'themes': {
      'stripes': true
    },
    'data': data
  },
  'contextmenu': {
    'items': function($node) {
      return {
        'Remove': {
          'separator_before': false,
          'separator_after': false,
          'label': 'Delete group',
          'action': function(obj) {

            if ($node.original.disableDelete) {
              document.write('deletion is forbidden for this node');
              return;
            }

            var nodes = $node.children.slice(0); // jstree behaves erratic if we try to move using $node.children directly, so we will clone the array to prevent this issue

            var $row = $(obj.reference[0].closest('li'));

            $tree.jstree('move_node', nodes, $node.parent, $row.index());

            $tree.jstree('delete_node', $node);

          }
        }
      };
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="jstree_demo"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css">
```

> Last but not least, how can I check the node type before removing?

I´ve added a small sample to show you how you can accomplish it. Check the declaration of a custom attribute `disableDeletion` to a node:

```
var data = [{'text': 'item 4 (you cannot delete this one)', 'disableDelete': true}]
```

And the validation in the context menu action:

```
if ($node.original.disableDelete) {
    document.write('deletion is forbidden for this node');
    return;
}
```

Comment: thanks! this is exaclty what I wanted - except for the validation, i found that  `if($tree.jstree('get_type', $node, false) != "group") return;` works better for me